# A string of codes connected to multiple strings.I have some doubts about the two dimensional array and the for loop. Thank you very much！

Tags: c

```
/* link many strings*/
#include<stdio.h>
char *mystrcat(char * strDest,  char * strSrc);

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    while(scanf("%d",&n))//输入要连接的字符串个数
    {
        if(n==0) break;//输入0结束
        else
        {
            char words[n][100];
            int i=0;
            int j;
            for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
            {
                while(fgets(words[i],100,stdin)!=NULL)
                {
                    j=0;
                    while(words[i][j]!='\n')
                           j++;
                    if(words[i][j]=='\n') words[i][j]='\0';break;
                }
            }//输入字符串
            for(i=n;i>0;i--)
            {
                 mystrcat(words[i-1],words[i]);
            }//连接这几个字符串
            fputs(words[0],stdout);//输出字符串
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
//strcat函数原型
char *mystrcat(char * strDest,char * strSrc)
{
  char *res=strDest;
  while(*strDest)strDest++;
  while(*strDest=*strSrc)
  {
    strDest++;
    strSrc++;
  }
  return res;
}
```

This is a string of correct code to connect multiple strings. But I think n should be n-1 in two for cycles. But if you change the n to n-1, you can only enter n-1 strings, one less than I think. Can you tell me where my idea is wrong?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve and what happens with this code. It is not clear how to help you.

Comment: Use english in comment blocks.

Comment: I want to use this string of code to connect n strings ( the stract function prototype is written by myself), and I think the n in the two for loops at the beginning should be n-1. But if it is changed to n-1, this string of code can only be entered and connected to n-1 strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
```

Accessing array index out of bound when `i=n` - this is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So of course indexing should be from `n-1` to `0`( at max) or `0` to `n-1`.

And also array indexing in C starts from `0`. So there are `n` elements that you are accessing, not `n-1`.

So corrections would be

```
for(i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
```

The thing is - you are reading in the `n` locations having index `0` to `n-1` on the array and then you concatenate them one by one and at last all concatenated strings will be in `words[0]`. You are printing it out.

The second loop would be like

```
        for(i=n-1;i>0;i--)
        {
             mystrcat(words[i-1],words[i]);
        }
```

The idea is no matter what while accessing array indices don't access array index out bound. Here you can simply write it like this as shown in the second case. The thing is here we have ensured that all the indices used are from `{0,1,2,3...,n-1}`.

First determine what you want to do, if you want to take `n` string and then try to concatenate them then yes you can. That's what is being done here. but a much cleaner way to do it would be that keep a different `result` string on which you will concatenate `n` strings. That will not overwrite or change the already inputted strings.

Comment: What I gave is a bunch of correct codes, which can connect n strings correctly. I share the same idea with you, but when I change n to n-1, I can only input and connect n-1 strings.

Comment: @昱文米.: The second loop's explanation is also given.

Comment: But if I change n to n -1, I can only type in and connect to n -1 strings, so you can explain that.

Comment: @昱文米.: If you change to the loop shown then it's concatenating `n` string!!!...isn't it obvious?

Comment: I'm just doing what you say, but only connecting n - 1 strings, is that an IDE problem?

Comment: @昱文米.L But i tried just now..it gives me correct result.